# How to configure startupmanager to show option to choose for different kernel versions during boot

Tags: kernel, startupmanager

I just installed startupmanager, but i doesn't show my installed kernel versions to choose during boot? How to enable this?

Comment: did you install burg?

Comment: do you get a option like " Default Operating system " for startupmanager.

Comment: burg isn't installed, in startup manager i can choose between different kernel versions and memtest. But here i can just change the default option. The optionsscreen on startup doesn't appear. Don't know what's the reason. Do i have to install Grub or Grub2 also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm very sorry if this is ridiculous, but since there are no other answers yet: you haven't forgotten to check the *"Show Bootloader Menu"* box in *"Boot Options" → "Misc"* have you?

In case you have:

As far as i understand, this program modifies `/etc/default/grub`. Open this file using something like `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`.

Now there are two interesting values:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

The first one is to set the timeout where grub doesn't show at all. The second one sets the timeout until grub hides itself when it's shown.

To always show the boot menu, set the values to what you see above.

**Note that GRUB is always hidden if the previous boot has not failed.** (It's actually the other way round I think, grub forces itself to show should the previous boot have failed)

to get rid of this behaviour, you can set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=` (empty value). This will always display grub.

Don't forget to run `update-grub` after you're done.

And **always back up this file before you change it**. Be really careful with this; If you break this file, you might have to recover GRUB using an Ubuntu CD. Have one handy just in case.